# Leetcode Problem 136. Single Number - How do I fix my code, and does the logic work?

Tags: python

When I run this code I get an error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'".
I don't understand why! nor what to do about it please help!

(also don't know if I can use .remove() )

Thank you, this is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        stack = []
        
        if len(nums) == 1:
            return nums
        
        i = 0
        while i < len(nums):
            if not stack:
                stack = stack.append(nums[i])
            elif stack and nums[i] not in stack:
                stack = stack.append(nums[i])
            elif nums[i] in stack[0]:
                stack = stack.remove(nums[i])
            i += 1
        return stack[0]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback error.  That said,  during each of the ```if``` conditions,  you're overwriting what ```stack``` is.    ```stack.append()``` doesn't return a value so the default return is ```None```.

Comment: `stack.append(...)` mutates the list in-place and returns `None`, remove the `stack = ` from each line where you append/remove as it's not necessary and is assigning `None` to `stack`